# Change default values of Gallery Block settings

Tags: gallery, block-editor

How to change the **Default Settings** of Gutenberg Gallery Block
[image]

When creating a new Gallery Block, I want the default values to be `Columns: 2` and `Crop Images: false`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think [this is possible in Gutenberg](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/10791) for the gallery block.

There [still isn't a unified way to modify these types of settings](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/20588) for blocks either (the panel, typically on the right-side of a desktop screen, is collectively called the Inspector Controls)